# What is the complete shloka for Vishnu with meaning?

Tags: vishnu, shloka

Can you please tell what is complete shloka of Vishnu with meaning that is below

> Shaantaakaaram bhujagashayanam padmanaabham suresham 
>   Vishwaa dharam Gagana Sadrusham Megha Varnam Subhangam
>   Lakshmi kantam kamalanayanam yogibhir dhyaana gamyam
>   Vande vishnum bhava bhaya haram sarva lokaika naatham.

Comment: This is the complete shloka.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shantakaram: Embodiment of Peace
>
> Bhujaga Shayanam: Reclining on a Serpent
>
> Padmanabham: Who has a lotus flower coming from his navel, from which Brahma was born
>
> Suresham: The Lord of the gods
>
> Vishwadharam: Sustainer of all things
>
> Gagana Sadrusham: Pervading the whole cosmos
>
> Megha Varnam: Whose skin is dark blue like rain clouds
>
> Shubhangam: With a pure and flawless body
>
> Lakshmi Kantam: Husband of the goddess Lakshmi
>
> Kamala Nayanam: Whose eyes are like lotus flowers
>
> Yogibhir Dhyana Gamyam: The one who practitioners of Yoga try to reach through meditation
>
> Vande Vishnum: I worship Vishnu
>
> Bhava Bhaya Haram: Remover of the fears of life
>
> Sarva Lokaika Natham: Lord of all of all worlds and universes

I take this from  [Keshav Srinivasan profile page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan)

Answer (score 1):

> शान्ताकारं भुजगशयनं पद्मनाभं सुरेशं
>   विश्वाधारं गगनसदृशं मेघवर्णं शुभाङ्गम् ।
>   लक्ष्मीकान्तं कमलनयनं योगिभिर्ध्यानगम्यम्
>   वन्दे विष्णुं भवभयहरं सर्वलोकैकनाथम् ॥

He, Who is of a calm countenance and reposes on one which moves with curves(id est snake- Lord Ananta); Who has a lotus navel(from which Brahma manifested), and Who is the Lord of all Gods; Who is the support of this World and is as vast as the Sky; and Who is of colour of a Black Cloud and has beautiful and auspicious body parts.

He, Who is the beloved of Lakshmi and Who has eyes like lotuses; Who is always approached by Ascetics in their state of Meditation; I worship that Vishnu, Who pervades everywhere, He, Who exterminates the fear of this illusionary world, and Who is the sole Lord of all the worlds.